# Error: Kotlin: Type inference failed on when expression

Tags: kotlin

```
val finalValue: Array<String> = arrayOf("A", "B", "C", "D")
when (value) {
  in finalValue  -> println("Pass")
  !in finalValue -> println("Not Pass")
}
```

> Error: Kotlin: Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter
> T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or
> expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

can you help me to solve this error? thanks

Comment: What is `value`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: fun main() {
    
    val value = 'A'

    when (value) {
        'A' -> println("Great")
        'B' -> println("Good")
        'C' -> println("Not Bad")
        'D' -> println("Bad")
        else -> println("Try Again!")
    }

    when (value) {
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' -> {
            println("Pass")
        }
        else -> {
            println("Try Again!")
        }
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: That code compiles and runs without errors by the way. What's the problem?

Comment: Kotlin: Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `value` is of type `Char` (based on your code in the comment)

You are trying to search a `Char` in a array of `String`. To fix this, you either need to change the array to `Array<Char>` or convert the `value` to String using `toString`

```
val value = 'A'
val finalValue: Array<Char> = arrayOf('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
when (value) {
  in finalValue  -> println("Pass")
  !in finalValue -> println("Not Pass")
}
```

or

```
val value = 'A'
val finalValue: Array<String> = arrayOf("A", "B", "C", "D")
when (value.toString()) {
  in finalValue  -> println("Pass")
  !in finalValue -> println("Not Pass")
}
```